# Touchpad Gesture Sensitivity (22.04)

Tags: touchpad, 22.04, multi-touch, gestures

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04, for the past few months now, and I discovered touchpad gestures a little while ago, and I love it, can't live without them. But the problem is that the gestures are wayy too sensitive on my computer at least, 1mm of movement and I fly off the screen.

Is there any way to alter the sensitivity of the touchpad gestures?? I've searched everywhere in Settings, and I have not found anyone with similar problems to try their solution. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust your Touchpad speed from
Setting >> Mouse & Touchpad >> Touchpad Speed

This image show you were you can adjust you Touchpad speed
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Bda.png

Comment: The touchpad itself has good sensitivity when I move the cursor, it's just the gestures that are too sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You might want to play with device quirk settings in `libinput`. See these two pages for details:

1. [Touchpad pressure debugging](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-pressure-debugging.html)
2. [Device quirks attributes](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-quirks.html#device-quirks)

I am using a late 2013 Macbook Pro and I managed to make my trackpad work quite nicely on Wayland thanks to `libinput`'s device quirk settings.

Good luck!